# Sharing code AND configuration using parent module in Maven

Tags: maven, inheritance, multi-module

In my project I have two modules `(A,B)` depend on common module `C`.
I would like `A,B` share common configuration, such as repository configuration, plugin configuration, etc. In order to achieve this, `C` is made the parent pom and `A,B` *inherit* from it (no aggregation is required, so `C` does not reference `A,B`)

However, `C` by itself contains some java code, along with unit tests. Now, if I run `mvn test` inside `C` nothing is executed. Supposedly, `pom`-packaged modules should not include any code.

Is the above configuration terribly flawed? Should yet another *common* pom be introduced even though one *already exists*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At very typical pattern in Maven projects is to have a module named "parent" which holds your common Maven-specific configuration, profiles, properties, dependency versions, etc.  This is The Maven Way (TM).

The structure looks something like the following:

```
|-- parent
|-- common
|-- module-a
|-- module-b
```

So, common, module-a and module-b each depend on parent, and module-a and module-b depend on common.

See this excellent resource:
http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-web-spring.html

Note that "parent" can be a sibling of its child modules, in terms of directory structure. There is no requirement that the directory structure hierarchy match that of the modules.

Comment: Thanks, Noahz! I was kinda afraid to hear it. Any idea why parent and common cannot be the same module, at least theoretically? Is there any fundamental issue here?

Comment: Single responsibility principle. No technical reason.

Comment: I have this same exact project structure, but want instead of having to produce three different jars (common, module-a, and module-b), I'd like to just build module-a and module-b, with the code in common appended to both. Is there any way to do this?